# XITS and \not\models

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, stix

When using XITS (with xelatex), the `\not` is displayed way too high on certain commands.  For instance:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\def\nerode{\equiv}
\begin{document}
\huge$\not\models \not\nerode \not\equiv$
\end{document}
```

is displayed:

[image]

That is, only the `\not\equiv` which is probably a glyph by itself, is properly printed.  Compare the above result with the following (without `unicode-math` and `XITS Math`):

[image]

What is the way to go to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: The glyphs are already available as `\nequiv` for ≢ and `\nvDash` for ⊭

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`unicode-math` should load predefined negation symbols when available, so `\not\equiv` is the same as `\nequiv`, but it seems not all aliases were taken care of (`\not\vDash` works but not `\not\models`).

`unicode-math` simply defines `\not` so that it checks the next csname, and if the there an `n` or `not` prefixed csname of that name, it will use it, else it will just put the slash.

A simple fix is to define `\n…` csnames of the ones that does not work for you, e.g.:

```
\let\nnerode\nequiv
\let\nmodels\nvDash
```

Answer (score 7):

Usually `\not` is only a poor man's solution, overlaying a slash like glyph with the relational symbols that follows. However, the result could be improved by ligatures to select the right glyph. Probably this is the case with `\not\equiv` here.

Both negated characters are directly available. And in `unicode-math-table.tex`
the macro names can be found:

- ≢: U+2262 NOT IDENTICAL TO: `\nequiv`
- ⊭: U+22AD NOT TRUE: `\nvDash`

Thus they can be used directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

$\nvDash\nequiv$ % standard names (unicode-math-table.tex)

$⊭≢$ % direct

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: The predefined commands for these symbols are `\nvDash` and `\nequiv` (according to `unimath-symbols`).

Comment: @Caramdir Thanks. Answer modified accordingly.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thanks for your answer!  Now I see that even `\not\in` is not the same as `\notin` in XITS.  Gosh, all those years...