# Negated binary or relation symbols in lualatex of xelatex

Tags: unicode-math

According to this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82121/16895 `\not` is defined (in `unicode-math`) to look for the next csname and to see if there is a csname prefixed with `n` or `not`.

However, when I use the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
$a\not= b$  $a\neq b$

$\not\vdash$  $\nvdash$

$\not\vDash$ $\nvDash$

$\not\equiv$ $\nequiv$
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

where clearly the combination of `\not\...` does not produce the same result as equivalent glyph.

Have I misunderstood the answer above? Or what is the proper way to negate a symbol (in most cases I would prefer to use `\not` for portability reasons, for example `\nequiv` is not available in most font, according to the comprehensive symbols guide, it is available in a few packages, and for example not in `amssymb`)

Comment: If I do `\show\not`, I get `\Umathaccent fixed 7\symoperators "00338\scan_stop:` which contradicts the answer you refer to. The behavior changed from TL 2013 and TL 2014

Comment: I opened a issue at the GitHub repository: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/279

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the passage from version 0.7e to 0.7f of `unicode-math` something changed and the definition

```
\cs_set_eq:NN \not \not_newnot:N
```

is now overridden by what's found in `unicode-math-table.tex`

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"00338}{\not}{\mathaccent}{combining long solidus overlay}
```

I guess that the loading order has changed.

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument{\cs_set_eq:NN \not \not_newnot:N}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$a\not= b$  $a\neq b$

$\not\vdash$  $\nvdash$

$\not\vDash$ $\nvDash$

$\not\equiv$ $\nequiv$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does it have to be at begin document? (Why doesn't it work in the preamble after `unicode-math` is loaded?) [I've thoroughly confused myself by trying to understand the syntax.]

Comment: @cfr `unicode-math` does almost all its work `\AtBeginDocument`

Comment: Thanks. I guessed it must be something like that but the syntax seems incredibly alien right now!

Comment: @egreg Doing the above workaround for `$\not\vdots$`, as the negation isn't vertically centered, leads to an unexpected result (like $6\vdots$). Any idea how to correct this (or how to negate the vertical ellipses symbol preferably without another package) please?

Comment: @egreg I'm answering my Q "how to negate the vertical ellipses" - I made a new symbol with `\def\nvdots{\mathrel/\joinrel\mkern-3.5mu\vdots}`